# Return a Value from the first Column matching Max()

Tags: excel, max

I have a table:

```
   A  B   C   D

   2  10  70  45

   2  20  80  55

   3  30  90  65

   3  40  15  76

   4  50  25  85

   4  60  35  95
```

I want to get the maximum from the array `B1:D6` which is 95 and return
   the value of the first column `A` which is 4

Comment: Use the MAX() function and then use the VLOOKUP() function or the INDEX/MATCH functions.

Comment: You need to clarify, what happens when we have multiple max match.

Comment: If there is a multiple max match, it will give you multiple values too. For example E5 and E6 has a value of 95, the answer would be 3, 4, 4. Please tell me it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you VBA Programmer, I don't want to add another column though, I was thinking of creating an array formula like {=MAX(B1:D6)} but I'm not sure how to get the value of the first column where it is in line with 95.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new column before column A and put the following formula in cell A2 and drag down:

```
=MAX(C2:E2)
```

Then put the following formula in cell H2:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(A2:A7), A2:B7, 2, FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]